# problem getting file url using php within img tag

Tags: php, html, css, file

I build a form to upload a image file in a folder using php. The uploading works and I can see the uploaded in file in my directory but when I try to retrive the same image url to display in a certain location, its not working. Here is my code

Im not uploading the whole upload.php file.

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],  $newfilename)) 
  {
        echo $newfilename;
        header("location: welcome.php");
        die();
    
  }
```

image location is welcome.php file

```
<div style="width: 140px; height: 150px; border-radius: 5px; background: #eee;">
         <? php echo $newfilename>
        <img src="<?php $newfilename>" width="140px" height="150px" alt="Upload photo" border-radius="10px"> 
    </div>
```

Also when I tried to echo `$newfilename` its showing diffrent value in upload.php file and welcome.php. Actually The file extension is missing, why so diffrence. The correct code to get the uploaded file url

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
src="<?php echo $newfilename; ?>"
```

echo value in src tag